# acstionscript 3 Loop object name Iterate object name

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, loops

I want to create a loop on some Sprite objects. Those objects are not in an array, but I named them like this : fixPT1, fixPT2...
I tried this but it wont work

```
function stopAll(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var num:Number = 1;
    if (dragPT1.x == destPt1.x && dragPT1.y == destPt1.y) {
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, pointMove);
    } else {
        dragPT1.x = fixPt1.x;
        dragPT1.y = fixPt1.y;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the .name property is set yo should be able to use array access notation: `this["fixPt"+num]` or use [getChildByName()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildByName())

Answer (score 0):

```
totalNumberOfSpriteObjects = 3; // or however many there are 
for( var i:int = 0; i < totalNumberOfSpriteObjects; i++ )
{
    var fixPoint = this[ 'fixPt' + (i+1) ];
    var dragPoint = this[ 'dragPT' + (i+1) ];
    var destPoint = this[ 'destPt' + (i+1) ];

    if ( dragPoint.x == destPt.x && dragPoint.y == destPt.y )
    {
        stage.removeEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, pointMove );
    }
    else
    {
        dragPoint.x = fixPoint.x;
        dragPoint.y = fixPoint.y;
    }
}
```